# Rails 4 - on the server, how do I list all the cookies and their values that have been sent from the client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

Ok, so I know that the client sends cookies to the server.  I'm working on a legacy rails app and I just want to access a particular cookie if it exists.  I need to do this in `application_controller.rb`.  To start, how do I simply list each cookie that was sent along with it's value?  Thanks much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your controller try the following:

```
cookies.each do |cookie|
  puts cookie
end
```

`cookie[0]` will be the name and `cookie[1]` will be the value.

Answer (score 4):

For a nicer output:

```rb
Rails.logger.debug(cookies.map { |cookie| cookie.join('=') }.join("\n"))
```

And watch your Rails log.